# How did you guess the eigenvalues of this matrix?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

[image]

As the text said, the educated guess for the lambda of the matrix are 1,2, and 3. Pardon, but how did we arrive at that conclusion? I don't really see how it works

Comment: It is not hard to guess that $\lambda=1$ is a root of this cubic polynomial. Then divide by $(\lambda-1)$ to obtain the quadratic polynomial, which you certainly can solve. Please don't use pictures of text or formulas. See
[here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem),
why. Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I suspect that the author used the so-called rational root theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: once you get to the cubic,  the rationl roots theorem says to check $\pm 1, \pm 2 , \pm 3 $

Comment: So this isn't about eigen values, rather about cubic polynomials?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the text book had a particular method in mind. as it says, it's just a guess. However, you could use the rational root test, which tells you if the polynomial has a rational root then it has to be one of:
$$1,2,3,6,-1,-2,-3,-6$$
once you have found a root "c" you can divide the polynomial by (x-c) to get polynomial of degree two and solve it.
generally speaking people normally check to see whether 1 or -1 are roots, since they're easy to check.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative solution** (without Rational Zero Theorem):
$$
\begin{aligned}
-\lambda^3+6\lambda^2-11\lambda+6 & = -(\lambda-2)^3+\lambda-2\\
& \\
& = (\lambda - 2)(1-(\lambda-2)^2)\\
& \\
& = (\lambda - 2)(1-\lambda^2+4\lambda-4)\\
& \\
& = -(\lambda - 2)(\lambda^2-4\lambda+3)\\
& \\
& = - (\lambda - 2)(\lambda - 1)(\lambda - 3).
\end{aligned}
$$